# Passing a input value from one method to another

Tags: java, input, methods

The following code is for a lab for the java course I'm taking for which just started the chapter on parameters and objects. I've hit a major choke-point past which I can't get past.

The issue I'm having is that I need to get the input assigned to destinationAmount, in the method GetAmountOfDestinations, to the method GetItinerary so I can use it in the for loop. I can't have any code within the main method other than the calls to the other methods. I cannot change the nature of the methods as the instructions say they must be made in a certain way.

Just how would I get the input to the other method? Do I create a third method to route the value through? I've looked for hours on this website and youtube and I haven't seen anything like this situation. I'd appreciate the help.

```
import java.util.*;
public class TripPlanner
{
  public static final Scanner CONSOLE = new Scanner ( System.in );
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    GetAmountOfDestinations();
    GetItinerary();
  }
  public static int GetAmountOfDestinations()
  {
    System.out.println( "Please enter the amount of destinations." );
    int destinationAmount = CONSOLE.nextInt();
    System.out.println( "You entered " + destinationAmount + "." );
  }
  public static void GetItinerary() 
  {

    System.out.println( "Your starting airport is SAT." );

    int amountOfDestinations = ??????;
    System.out.println(amountOfDestinations);

    double currentDestinationLatitude = Airports.getAirportLatitude( "SAT" );
    double currentDestinationLongitude = Airports.getAirportLongitude( "SAT" );
    for( int x = 0; x <  amountOfDestinations; x = x + 1 )
    {
      System.out.println( "Please enter the next destination." );
      String nextDestination = CONSOLE.next();

      double nextDestinationLatitude = Airports.getAirportLatitude( nextDestination );
      double nextDestinationLongitude = Airports.getAirportLongitude( nextDestination );

      System.out.println( nextDestinationLatitude + " " + nextDestinationLongitude );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the answer to question is in your question itself. Its a chapter on parameters and objects. You can pass parameters to methods .. e.g. public static void GetItinerary(int amountOfDestinations) and then use it in the method

Comment: Stick to the Java Naming Convention! Methods must start with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a return on your GetAmountOfDestinations then call the method when you're trying t get the amountOfDestinations:

```
public static int GetAmountOfDestinations()
  {
    System.out.println( "Please enter the amount of destinations." );
    int destinationAmount = CONSOLE.nextInt();
    System.out.println( "You entered " + destinationAmount + "." );
    return destinationAmount;
  }
```

In the GetItinerary you assign the value:

```
int amountOfDestinations = GetAmountOfDestinations();
```

Comment: When I do this, I get a repeat of the method GetAmountOfDestinations(). It works fine from there but it does repeat itself for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that `GetAmountOfDestinations()` is declared to return an `int`. You need to add a `return` statement to this method in order for it to compile.

Second, you will then need to assign the returned value to a variable. There are two different ways to do this:

1. Assign the returned value to a variable in `main()` and then pass it to `GetItinerary()`:

   ```
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
     int dest = GetAmountOfDestinations();
     GetItinerary(dest);
   }
   ```

   This requires you to change `GetItinerary()` to accept an `int` parameter, rather than have a local variable:

   ```
   public static void GetItinerary(int amountOfDestinations)
   ```

   Now remove the local variable declaration.
2. Another solution is to call `GetAmountOfDestinations()` directly from `GetItinerary()`:

   int amountOfDestinations = GetAmountOfDestinations();

   Then remove the call to `GetAmountOfDestinations()` from `main()`.

Comment: I may not have been clear. The lab instructions say there can be no other code in the main method other than to call the other methods. So No.1 is a no-go. As for No.2, that method must be called from the main method. It can't be called from GetItinerar.

Comment: @DariusB #1 **does** only have code which calls the other methods. When you are learning about passing parameters and returning values, these are the only two options you have. If you must call `GetItinerary()` from `main()` then the first, or some slight variation is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read more about method return values and parameters to make sense of the code below. But all you need to do is use the value returned from one method and pass it as a parameter to the next method to achieve what you are trying to do.

```
import java.util.*;
public class TripPlanner
{
  public static final Scanner CONSOLE = new Scanner ( System.in );
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    int amtDestinations = GetAmountOfDestinations();
    GetItinerary(amtDestinations);
  }
  public static int GetAmountOfDestinations()
  {
    System.out.println( "Please enter the amount of destinations." );
    int destinationAmount = CONSOLE.nextInt();
    System.out.println( "You entered " + destinationAmount + "." );
    return destinationAmount
  }
  public static void GetItinerary(int amountOfDestinations) 
  {

    System.out.println( "Your starting airport is SAT." );

    System.out.println(amountOfDestinations);

    double currentDestinationLatitude = Airports.getAirportLatitude( "SAT" );
    double currentDestinationLongitude = Airports.getAirportLongitude( "SAT" );
    for( int x = 0; x <  amountOfDestinations; x = x + 1 )
    {
      System.out.println( "Please enter the next destination." );
      String nextDestination = CONSOLE.next();

      double nextDestinationLatitude = Airports.getAirportLatitude( nextDestination );
      double nextDestinationLongitude = Airports.getAirportLongitude( nextDestination );

      System.out.println( nextDestinationLatitude + " " + nextDestinationLongitude );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Code-Apprentice It is basically the code in the question. The only changes i made were to indicate as to how he can modify it to his needs. I didn't really compile the code myself. I tried formatting the code to bold to indicate the point of changes, but it just showed up as asterisks as it was a code block.

Comment: That is my point. The code in the question has several errors. Your answer does not fix the one which is directly related to the question.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I get your concern. I am not really trying to solve the compilation issue for him. My intent was to get across the idea that methods could be parametrized and how he could pass/return values to/from methods. Thanks for pointing that out but I would rather let him figure out the compilation errors on his own :)

Comment: I agree that the general content of learning how to use methods is exactly what the OP needs. I definitely should have commented about that part. While you are at it, you should also show how to fix the line `int amountOfDestinations = ??????;` is exactly what the OP is asking about. Since `??????` is not valid Java, it causes an error. (Hint: Just remove it since your solution does not need it.)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I guess he left that as ??? because he was not able to figure out how to pass the intended value from other method to this method.